# How do I write this complicated email template structure?

Tags: html, css, email, html-table, html-email

This is about an email template with each table containing an item with a picture on the right side and the details on the left side with the name/brand name/ size and so on.
I have tried a bunch of different solutions I have found online but I can't get the structure to be responsive enough for all platforms.
Any resource regarding the structure is helpful. I made a picture to describe what the structure looks like.

[image]

Another user pointed out that I could show the last template I tried and a resource I used that didn't work out well.
https://codepen.io/Georgeslatina/pen/gOGzavj

```html
<table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="580" style="margin: auto;height: 220px; table-layout: fixed; border: solid 1px #efefef; background-color: #fdfdfd; padding: 20px;margin-bottom:28px !important;direction:ltr !important">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="60%">
        <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="text-align: right; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; height: 180px;">
          <tbody>
            <tr style="width: 100%;height:20%;">
              <td colspan="60%" style="">
                <div style="word-wrap: break-word;padding-right:12px;font-size:18px"> text2</div>
              </td>
              <td colspan="5%" style="">
                <div style="height: 20px; width: 1px;  background-color: black; margin: auto;">
                </div>
              </td>
              <td colspan="35%" style="">
                <div style="font-size:20px;word-wrap: break-word;padding-right:22%"> text1</div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="44%" style="">
                <div style="padding-right:10px">
                  <span> ₪100  </span>
                  <span style="padding-left:8px"> מחיר</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td colspan="2%" style="">
                <div style="height: 20px; width: 1px;  background-color: #e6e6e6; margin: auto;">
                </div>
              </td>
              <td colspan="24%" style="">
                <div style="padding-right:20%">
                  <span style="padding-left:8px">L </span>
                  <span>מידה</span>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td colspan="2%" style="">
                <div style="height: 20px; width: 1px;  background-color: #e6e6e6; margin: auto;">
                </div>
              </td>
              <td colspan="13%" style="padding-right:8px">
                <div style="border-radius:50%; width: 11px; height: 11px; border: 2px solid black; margin-left:65%">
                  <div style="width: 9px; height: 9px;border-radius:50%; margin:auto; margin-top:1px"></div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td colspan="11%">
                <div style="float:left">צבע</div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td colspan="100%" style="padding-right:30px;height:30px">
                <div style="text-align:right">
                  <span>
                                reason 
                                </span>
                  <span style="text-align:right;font-family:NarkisBlockMF;font-size:18px;font-weight: 550;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.28;letter-spacing: normal;color: #000;">  :סיבת החזרה</span>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td colspan="25%" style="position: relative">
        <div style="display:block;width:135px; height:180px;text-align: center; font-size: 0; background:url('https://i.natgeofe.com/n/46b07b5e-1264-42e1-ae4b-8a021226e2d0/domestic-cat_thumb_square.jpg') no-repeat center; background-size: cover">
        </div>
        <div style="
                position:absolute;
                z-index: 1;
                bottom:0;
                width: 135px;
                height: 24px;
                opacity: 0.8;
                font-family:NarkisBlockMF;
                font-size:17px;
                background-color: #000;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                line-height: 24px;">
          פריט החזרה
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the conditional VML in the example down did not work in my tests.
https://stackoverflow.design/email/templates/short-transactional/

Comment: Try exploring flex/grid in CSS. You need two divs/sections one on left and another on right.

Comment: Hi, this site is for developers helping other developers. For us to be able to assist you, we need to see your efforts. What have you tried so far? Please share your code, your attempts, trials and what exactly you're struggling with. This is not a site "we-are-doing-your-work.com"

Comment: @kiner_shah Hey, Flex/grid isn't supported on most email clients.

Comment: @toesslab Hey, sorry if it seemed like I was asking for the whole thing. I was asking for anything helpful, any resource that is responsive on all clients since I have tried the first few pages I found on google and they don't work as intended.

Comment: @toesslab This is the last template that I did and it is nowhere close on outlook/mail. 
https://codepen.io/Georgeslatina/pen/gOGzavj and if I were to cite one source I used that didn't really work for me it would be https://stackoverflow.design/email/templates/short-transactional/

Comment: @htmlbeginner5, if not flex/grid, you can use table. Not sure what is an ideal way to code such a table, but one thing I can come up with without much thinking is that you can have three tables each having just one row and columns are as per your expected layout.

Comment: BTW, you can include what you tried within the post itself - maybe there are few fixes which can solve your issue.

Comment: @kiner_shah Tables that I have tried don't work well enough on outlook/windows mail and they break. If anything I am looking for some VML advice/resources that could help me build the template.

Comment: Tables will work (try nesting tables instead of using colspan or rowspan), however, what do you want the layout to look like in mobile? That will dictate the overall structure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hybrid method of achieving what you have in your image. My code is not dependent on media queries but I have added a class in to make my blocks 100% width in mobile. If that is removed, the row with text3, text2 and text1 will start stacking on their own as it reaches smaller screen size.

I have not put in any pipes/seperators as they can be placed when you add your content in.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
/*not smart phones*/
@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
    .fullWidth{width:100% !important;max-width:100% !important;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<table width="700" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" width="700">
<![endif]--> 
            
            <!-- start 700 pixel container -->
            
            <table width="700" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="fullWidth" style="max-width:700px;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; font-size: 0px; padding: 0px;"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<table width="700" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" width="350">
<![endif]-->
                            
                            <div style="max-width: 349px; width:100%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; font-size: 0px; padding: 0px;"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                            <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="175">
                                            <![endif]-->
                                                
                                                <div style="max-width: 174px; width:100%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
                                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;">text1</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
                                                
                                                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                                </td><td align="left" valign="top" width="175">
                                                <![endif]-->
                                                
                                                <div style="max-width: 174px; width:100%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
                                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;">text2</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
                                                
                                                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            <![endif]--></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; font-size: 0px; padding: 0px;"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                            <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="116">
                                            <![endif]-->
                                                
                                                <div style="max-width: 116px; width:100%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;" class="fullWidth">
                                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;">text3</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
                                                
                                                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                            </td><td align="left" valign="top" width="116">
                                            <![endif]-->
                                                
                                                <div style="max-width: 116px; width:100%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;" class="fullWidth">
                                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;">text2</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
                                                
                                                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                            </td><td align="left" valign="top" width="116">
                                            <![endif]-->
                                                
                                                <div style="max-width: 116px; width:100%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;" class="fullWidth">
                                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;">text1</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
                                                
                                                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            <![endif]--></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; font-size: 0px; padding: 0px;"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                            <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="left" valign="top" width="116">
                                            <![endif]-->
                                                
                                                <div style="max-width: 116px; width:100%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;" class="fullWidth">
                                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;"></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
                                                
                                                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                            </td><td align="left" valign="top" width="116">
                                            <![endif]-->
                                                
                                                <div style="max-width: 116px; width:100%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;" class="fullWidth">
                                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;">text2</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
                                                
                                                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                            </td><td align="left" valign="top" width="116">
                                            <![endif]-->
                                                
                                                <div style="max-width: 116px; width:100%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;" class="fullWidth">
                                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;">text1</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
                                                
                                                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            <![endif]--></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
</td><td align="left" valign="top" width="350">
<![endif]-->
                            
                            <div style="max-width: 349px; width:100%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;">image</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;">text</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<![endif]--></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            
            <!-- start 700 pixel container --> 
            
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<![endif]--></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont set your layout in a single table, seperate them into two tables. Table for content and table for image.

```html
<style>
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .module-wrapper, .grid{
      width: 100% !important;
    }
    .grid{
      float: none !important;
    }
  }
</style>

<table class="module-wrapper" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="580" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <!--[if mso]><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" dir="rtl"><tr><td valign="top" dir="ltr"><![endif]-->
      <table class="grid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="135" align="right">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="position: relative">
              <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div style="display:block;width:135px; height:180px;text-align: center; font-size: 0; background:url('https://i.natgeofe.com/n/46b07b5e-1264-42e1-ae4b-8a021226e2d0/domestic-cat_thumb_square.jpg') no-repeat center; background-size: cover">
                    </div>
                    <div style="
                            position:absolute;
                            z-index: 1;
                            bottom:0;
                            width: 135px;
                            height: 24px;
                            opacity: 0.8;
                            font-family:NarkisBlockMF;
                            font-size:17px;
                            background-color: #000;
                            color: white;
                            text-align: center;
                            line-height: 24px;">
                      פריט החזרה
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              
            </td>
          </tr>
      </table><!-- #end image table -->
      <!--[if mso]></td><td valign="top" dir="ltr"><![endif]-->
      <table class="grid" role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="445" align="left">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="60%">
              <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                style="text-align: right; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; height: 180px;">
                <tbody>
                  <tr style="width: 100%;height:20%;">
                    <td colspan="60%" style="">
                      <div style="word-wrap: break-word;padding-right:12px;font-size:18px"> text2</div>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="5%" style="">
                      <div style="height: 20px; width: 1px;  background-color: black; margin: auto;">
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="35%" style="">
                      <div style="font-size:20px;word-wrap: break-word;padding-right:22%"> text1</div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="44%" style="">
                      <div style="padding-right:10px">
                        <span> ₪100 </span>
                        <span style="padding-left:8px"> מחיר</span>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2%" style="">
                      <div style="height: 20px; width: 1px;  background-color: #e6e6e6; margin: auto;">
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="24%" style="">
                      <div style="padding-right:20%">
                        <span style="padding-left:8px">L </span>
                        <span>מידה</span>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2%" style="">
                      <div style="height: 20px; width: 1px;  background-color: #e6e6e6; margin: auto;">
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="13%" style="padding-right:8px">
                      <div style="border-radius:50%; width: 11px; height: 11px; border: 2px solid black; margin-left:65%">
                        <div style="width: 9px; height: 9px;border-radius:50%; margin:auto; margin-top:1px"></div>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="11%">
                      <div style="float:left">צבע</div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
    
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="100%" style="padding-right:30px;height:30px">
                      <div style="text-align:right">
                        <span>
                          reason
                        </span>
                        <span
                          style="text-align:right;font-family:NarkisBlockMF;font-size:18px;font-weight: 550;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.28;letter-spacing: normal;color: #000;">
                          :סיבת החזרה</span>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </table><!-- #end content table -->
      <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table><!-- #end module-wrapper -->
```

Then use media query to make your table responsive

If you dont want to use media query try using the method from this article
https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-future-proof-responsive-email-without-media-queries--cms-23919

Answer (score -1):

I tried to use CSS grid for this

```css
#parent-container {
  border: 0.2rem solid black;
  padding: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  place-content: center;
}

#parent-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
}

.first-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}

.first-container div:nth-child(1) {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  place-items: center;
}

.first-container div:nth-child(2) {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  place-items: center;
}

.first-container div:nth-child(3) {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  place-items: center;
}

.first-container div>div:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 0.2rem solid black;
}

.first-container div {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.second-container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: 0.2rem solid black;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="parent-container">
    <!-- first container-child -->
    <div class="first-container">
      <div>
        <div>text1</div>
        <div>text2</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>text3</div>
        <div>text2</div>
        <div>text1</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div>text2</div>
        <div>text1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- second container-child -->
    <div class="second-container">
      <img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4" alt="">
      <div>text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the effort but as seen on https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ grid and a lot of other css isn't supported on most email clients, which is why I have trouble with the template.